# How can a "noun suffix" be used for words that don't fit into the pattern i.e. "family"? Family-ness? Family-like? Familiality (made up word...)

Tags: nouns, suffixes

I am editing a document for someone and they used the word "familiness" to relate to the family-like nature of an organisation. Is there a better word to use than the phrase "family-like nature"?

Comment: *Familiality* appears to be in use.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[kinship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinship)**

> kinship
>   : the state of being related to the people in your family
>   : a feeling of being close or connected to other people

Comment: Not bad, but the meaning of consanguinity might confuse the issue.

Comment: @deadrat:  I see it as a**kin** to family in the that regard, the same **kin**d of metaphor, although you've now got me considering "camaraderie" or the ever popular "team" as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ***familial***

> of or relating to a family : suggesting a family - [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/familial)

Comment: That's an adjective, not a noun.

Comment: What deadrat says is right, although it could be made into a noun "familiality."